# Hide a component when another is hovered

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby for a static website.

My page is composed of two parts. Section 1 and Section 2.
I want to hide an image in Section 1, when a button is hovered in Section 2.

If I clean up a bit my .js, it looks like that :

```
<section>
    <SomeText/>
    <DefaultImage />
    <ImageOne />
    <ImageTwo />
</section>

<section>
    <Button1/>
    <Button2/>
</section>
```

What I want to achieve:
By default, `<DefaultImage/>` is shown.
If I hover `<Button1>`, I want to hide `<DefaultImage/>` and display `<ImageOne/>` instead.

Same goes for `<Button2/>`, which, when hovered, should hide `<DefaultImage/>` and display `<ImageTwo/>`.

I've read about onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave, and I think that the answer lies there but couldn't make it work for now.

Thank you for your ideas!

Maybe I can also pass a prop (like a css class) on the "to be hidden" component when the other is hovered

I managed to do it (check the accepted answer).
Here is my edited code:

````
class Parent extends Component {

    state = {
      isHoveringImage1: false
    }
    state = {
        isNotHovering: false
      }
      state = {
        isHoveringImage2: false
      }  

    startHoverMasque = () => this.setState({ isHoveringMasque: true, isNotHovering: true})
    stopHoverMasque = () => this.setState({ isHoveringMasque: false, isNotHovering: false })
    startHoverMains = () => this.setState({ isHoveringMains: true, isNotHovering: true})
    stopHoverMains = () => this.setState({ isHoveringMains: false, isNotHovering: false })

    render() {
      return (
        <>
        <Global 
    styles={globalStyles}/>

          <section>
          {
              this.state.isNotHovering
                ? <ImageDefaultHidden />
                : <ImageDefault/>
            }
            {
              this.state.isHoveringImage1
                ? <Image1 />
                : <ImageDefaultHidden />
            }
            {
              this.state.isHoveringImage2
                ? <Image2 />
                : <ImageDefaultHidden />
            }
          </section>
          <section>
            <Button1
              onMouseEnter={ this.startHoverImage1}
              onMouseLeave={ this.stopHoverImage1 }
            >Bouton1</Button1>
            <Button2
            onMouseEnter={ this.startHoverImage2}
            onMouseLeave={ this.stopHoverImage2 }
            >Bouton 2</Button2>
          </section>

        </>
      )
    }

  }
  export default Parent```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate when the mouse enter and leaves the target `Button` in the `state` of your parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    isHovering: false
  }

  startHover = () => this.setState({ isHovering: true })
  stopHover = () => this.setState({ isHovering: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <section>
          <SomeText/>
          {
            this.state.isHovering
              ? <ImageOne />
              : <DefaultImage />
          }
          <ImageTwo />
        </section>

        <section>
          <Button1
            onMouseEnter={ this.startHover }
            onMouseLeave={ this.stopHover }
          />
          <Button2/>
        </section>
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I used.

But as I wanted to also hide default image when hovering, I added a few things (I edited my original post to post the solution) :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include the variable saying whether or not your image should be rendered in your parent component's state.

To set this variable, pass down a function to the component containing the button and bind it to the events you gave in your question : `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.

Working example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
   hideImage: false
  }
 }

 toggleImage = hideImage => ev => {
  this.setState({ hideImage })
 }

 render = () => {

  return(
   <div>
    <ButtonComponent hovered={this.toggleImage}/>
    <ImageComponent isHidden={this.state.hideImage}/>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

const ButtonComponent = ({ hovered }) => <button onMouseEnter={hovered(true)} onMouseLeave={hovered(false)}>Hover me :)</button>

const ImageComponent = ({ isHidden }) => <img hidden={isHidden} src='https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'/>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```